# Changing git repository to new server

Tags: git, nginx

I have my git projects running on my NGINX server, but now I am posting everything to an online gitlab server from our development company we used before. I want to change this repo to our just set up bitbucket repository but I cannot figure out how to add or change this.

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org:account-name/repo-name.git
```

When I post the command the output is: fatal: remote origin already exists.

Comment: Do you want to use *both* the old URL *and* the new URL for some period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify to the point of a slight oversimplification, in Git, a *remote* is just a simple name, like `origin` or `upstream` or `github` or `beeblebrox` or whatever, for *a* (as in one, single) URL.  (You can in fact have more than one URL attached to any one remote name, but that's not meant for this kind of usage.)

You have been using one URL, which you have been calling `origin`.

Now you wish to use another URL.

You *cannot* add a second `origin`.  You *can* add a second *remote*, but you must not call it `origin`, because you already have an `origin`.  If you wish to call this new remote `howdy-doody`, you would use `git remote add howdy-doody new-url`.

You can also *change* the URL associated with the name origin, so if you don't want to use both URLs, you can simply *replace* the URL for the (single) remote named `origin`, using `git remote set-url origin new-url`.